# Multer file filtering based on MIME type

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have the code below. I would like use multer to accept only documents with the MIME type for docx. Otherwise, I would like to produce an error. I plan on doing vetting on the front-end as well, but for security purposes would like to implement here as well. The following code is returning an error, can anybody tell me where i am wrong?

```
const multer = require('multer')
const fs = require('fs')

const upload = multer({
  dest: './upload',
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
      if (req.file.mimetype != 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
          return cb(new Error('Wrong file type'))
      }
      cb(null,true)
  }
}).single('file');

app.post('/upload', upload, function(req, res) {

  console.log(req.file);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me when I used `file.mimetype` instead of `req.file.mimetype`.

```
fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    if (file.mimetype != 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
        return cb(new Error('Wrong file type'));
    }
    cb(null, true)
  }
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code snippet to accept only file type of docx:

```
 const filefilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (
      file.mimetype === "application/msword" ||
      file.mimetype ===            
      "application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
    ) {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(null, false);
    }
  };
```